# What is the meaning of this sentence (specifically 前まで)?

Tags: translation

> ちょっと前まで、ちょっと前まで暑かったです。

I'm following a video, and trying to translate line by line. This sentence I got stuck on.

I'm trying to break in down into parts.

I know `ちょっと` is "a little."

What is `前まで` here? I know `今まで` is "until now." So in that line of thinking, it leaves me somewhat confused.

And I know `暑かった` is the i-adjective `暑い`, but past tense. So was hot.

So roughly ...

> [...?] it was hot.

Comment: Check jisho at least....https://jisho.org/word/%E5%89%8D-1

Comment: @sundowner Weird of you to presume I hadn't already done that. I get you're an advanced user, but to me as a complete beginner, that page does not answer my question regarding `前まで`. I did not ask for the meaning of `前`.

Comment: I mean, you should show it in your question, just like you did for other parts. If *until before* does not make sense to you, making that explicit makes it easier to answer.

Comment: @sundowner It's literally asked in my question...I specify `前まで`.

Comment: I'm not blaming or anything, but I wondered why you didn't say you understood it as *until before* if you knew 今まで as *until now* and (implicitly) 前 as *before*. To me, *until before* looks close enough to *until a short while ago*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "(until) just a little while ago / just now."

> ちょっと前までここにいたのに
>
> But he was here just a little while ago.

> ちょっと前まで、ちょっと前まで暑かったです。
>
> Just now... just now, it was (still) hot.

You'll find a few more examples [here](https://ameblo.jp/motherhythm/entry-12611716223.html).